# Cannot install icons or themes from gnome-look with ocs-url

Tags: icons, themes, ubuntu-mate

up to now; I installed icons and themes for ubuntu-mate (LTS20.04) through gnome-look.org with the help of ocs-url. Now it does not work...

I have ocs-url installed, I choose an icon, press "install", choose the file from the drop-down menu, then "install" again - and nothing happens - no questioning to continue...

What is wrong?

B.

Comment: try `tail -f /var/log/syslog`  leave the terminal open, run through the same process you just described in your question and check the terminal for output.  This should provide at least a starting point for tracking this down.  Also provide the computer you are running this on in your question.

Comment: Thank you for quick response/advice.

Comment: Thank you for quick response/advice, I ran the given command, repeated process, no changes. I also tried same procedure on my (no-name) desktop with a theme, an icon theme and a wallpaper: same result/failure. Here, I work with an HP Probook 430 G6. in the afternoon; I installed xubuntu on a friend's ten-year-olf Apple MacPro Laptop, there ocs-url worked; I could install icons and themes.

Comment: Ok so from you what you describe it seems that xubuntu has some sort of package functionality that works with this gnome theme/ocs-url.  It doesn't seem to be related to the pc/laptop necessarily that I can tell.  Are you able to load this through the Ubuntu Software Store vice installing it via the website?

Comment: OK. Thanks, yes; I can find other ways installing different looks, after all it is not so important. It is just annoying, since up to now it worked, but I do not remember, if I ever tried install icons under ocs-url with Ubuntu 20.04, it was so easy. Too bad, maybe the software developers will see the problem... and fix it. Thank you again.

Comment: So there is now snap store and snap packages installed.  That and also "core" I believe that affected a few things with package installs.

Comment: Indeed, snap is installed. Anyways, maybe it will be fixed....

Comment: So I noticed that xbuntu uses the Xfce Desktop environment vice the Gnome Desktop which is the default in 20.04 `$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`  `ubuntu:GNOME`  If you are curious I would try running 20.04 virtually or from a live disk and try replacing the Gnome with Xfce (If that's even a possibility) OR try running another version that uses Xfce and see if that also works.

Comment: Thank you for help. Honestly, I regard myself as an amateur, so I am afraid realising your suggestion - therefore I rather abstain from OCS-URL. What I do/did now is downloading the wanted icon set/theme and then placing the folder into the /usr/share/themes or /usr/share/icons folders with the help of Caja (Mate's file manager, I think it is Nautilus in "normal" Ubuntu)  which I start in the terminal and the sudo command. This sounds complicated, I know - but since I do not change icons or themes often, it is fine. Thank you for help, I will try from time to time whether the problem was fixed